# I am writing a simple number program but an error pops up when I use elif saying I need a colon but I have one already

Tags: python-2.7

```
    number = raw_input
    print (raw_input('Please enter a number between 1 - 50 :'))
    if number <= 10:
    print('your number is between 0-10')
    elif number <= 20 and  >=11:   <---- when i put >=11: it gives the error
    print('your number is between 11-20')
    elif number <
     elif number <= 20 and  >=11:
                        ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
any tips or ideas?

Comment: `elif number <= 20 and number >=11:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a took this code that I just wrote:

```
number = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 - 50:"))
    if number <= 10:
        print("Your number is between 0-10")
    elif number <= 20 and number >= 11:
        print("Your number is between 11-20")
```

First, to answer your question, you needed to say "elif number <= 20 and number >= 11:
This is because the 'and' in Python separates the two statements, if you will. Thus after the 'and' you need to remind Python which variable you are using.

On a side note, I only have Python 3 installed so 'raw_input' did not work (as it has been removed). <strike>I would consider using input instead in the future as it will stay supported.</strike> The only problem is that it returns a string, so you need to cast it to an integer to do what you want to do.

Also one more thing, you can comment in Python by using a hash:

```
 #this is a comment and Python will ignore it
```

**EDIT:** Python 2.7's 'raw_input' is equivalent to Pythons 3's 'input' so continue to use that unless you upgrade to Python 3.

Comment: You only need one `#` not two.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Oops! My bad. Haven't used Python in a while :P

Comment: @E.Pang Glad to have helped! Could you please click on the arrow next to the question to mark it as correct?

Comment: Sure - just did it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
def get_number(number):
if (number < 10):
    print "number<10 ",number
elif (number>=11 and number<=20):
    print "11<number>20 ",number
elif (number<50):
    print "number<50 ",number
else:
    print "type proper number"


number = raw_input("enter number between 1 - 50");
get_number(int(number)) ##raw_input reads string, so convert number in int
```